# How to cache dnscrypt-proxy with dnsmasq+resolvconf?

Tags: network-manager, dnsmasq, dnscrypt-proxy

Due to my ISP intercepting some DNS requests and return 'redirected' A records, I want to use **dnscrypt-proxy** on my computer (my workstation, actually, running **Ubuntu 16.04**)

What I have done is install dnscrypt-proxy and point it to one of the public dnscrypt servers available. Then I change the DNS Server settings in Network Manager to point to 127.0.2.1 (the default listening address of dnscrypt-proxy)

It works, but it seems that every single resolve of FQDN goes to the dnscrypt server, and no caching is being performed.

So, I want to **cache DNS resolution done by dnscrypt**. I know I can do this using unbound, but dnsmasq is already installed on my workstation, so I want to use that instead. However, I'm a bit confused with the interaction between dnsmasq & resolvconf & Network Manager.

That leads to My Questions:

> How do I configure my system so DNS Resolution will be done by dnscrypt-proxy but cached by dnsmasq?

Comment: Which version of `dnscrypt-proxy` are you using exactly? Version 2 is supposed to do use a cache. How did you ascertain that caching is not being performed?

Answer (score 0):

You should first edit the NetworkManager config file in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and change the line that says `dns=dnsmasq` to `dns=none`. Then restart the NetworkManager service using `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`.

Install dnsmasq with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install dnsmasq -y`.
Edit the dnsmasq config in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` using your preferred editor.
Delete the whole config, and replace it with this:

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1  
port=53  
domain-needed  
bogus-priv  
dnssec  
proxy-dnssec  
strict-order  
no-resolv  
no-poll  
server=127.0.2.1  
cache-size=1000  
neg-ttl=3600  
dns-forward-max=150  
bind-interfaces
```

Then, stop and disable resolvconf using `sudo systemctl stop resolvconf && sudo systemctl disable resolvconf` and restart and enable dnsmasq using `sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq && sudo systemctl enable dnsmasq`. Edit `/etc/resolv.conf` using your preferred editor. Change it to only have one line:

`nameserver 127.0.0.1`

Now, test your internet connection by pinging a web address, for example `google.com`. If you get a response, it means that your setup is working!